# JavaScriptSerializer. Возвращается back slash "\" после обработки обьекта

Tags: c#, json.net

Есть проблема: после обработки объекта с помощью JavaScriptSerializer возвращается некорректный формат json. Использование JsonConvert не помогает. Есть гипотеза, что это проблема из-за того, что Web API .NET 2-ой раз сериализует уже сериализованный ответ.

[image: строка после сериализации]

Comment: Что конкретно Вас не устраивает в значении переменной `json`, и почему Вы думаете, что формат некорректный?

Comment: Планируется, что эта строка будет парситься на стороне приложения Swift (iOS). Насколько я понимаю, символ  \  (обратный слэш) будет препятствовать парсингу.

Comment: В строке нет слэша. `\"` - обозначение двойной кавычки внутри C#-овской строки. Попробуйте сохранить `json` в файл.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать стандартные возможности WebAPI для возврата json? [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Там тоже будут "слэши" (.

Comment: @Igor нет, там как раз можно настроить выдачу формата json без использования сериалайзера JavaScriptSerializer и тому подобных путем изменения настроек Web API. Дело в том, что мне надо передать сложный обьект, и при его передаче не получается возвращать его через return корректно. Создание файла и его передача на скачку тоже не сильно красивое решение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сложность в том, что при передаче объекта main root с помощью встроенного сериализатора Web API к нему не получается применить корректно ToList(), чтобы Web API выдало json. Такое получается сделать, если я возвращаю в результате db.Tables.ToList(). Тогда обратный слэш действительно не появляется.

Comment: Блин, нет у вас никаких слэшей в строке! Igor уже писал вам, что слэш только в режиме отладки показывается. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz3qI.png - обратите внимание, я использовал строку с `@` и вставил кавычки внутрь как `""` (это одна кавычка). А в режиме отладки (в окне Locals) строка показана со слэшами. Нажмите на стрелочку вниз рядом с лупой и выберите JSON visualizer - убедитесь сами.

Comment: Нажмите на лупу на вашем скриншоте и увидите что именно представляет собой ваша срока

Comment: @DavidAkobiya Я не предлагал скачивать файл, а просто хотел убедить Вас взглянуть на эти строковые данные **не** через отладчик Visual Studio.

Comment: Большое спасибо за комментарии. Я посмотрел через визулизатор json, и там все корректно отразилось https://pastenow.ru/5CNHU, но моя проблема заключается в том, что \ появляется во View после передачи через Web API https://pastenow.ru/5CNIU. Также если передавать на прямую string = "value" кавычки во View отображаются корректно: https://pastenow.ru/5CNH9

Comment: В показанном на скриншоте коде не используется View. Строка напрямую возвращается из контроллера.

Comment: В итоге проблема решилась только после переноса API в другой контроллер, так как стандартный ValueController осуществляет повторную сериализацию ответа.